# JQuery appendTo working fine but not rendering on the page

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, append

im doing some ajax function and everything is working well , im adding clients with their custom form and then sending data to a view how give a JsonResponse so the ajax call is working , but when i wanna add the created client with JQuery its show me on the dev tool that the DIV is added but like nothing is showed on the page like its transparant their is my code and thank you for your help :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var csrfToken = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

    $("#btn-submit").click(function() {
        var serializedData = $("#ClientForm").serialize();
        console.log("hey hey clients!");
        $.ajax({ 
                   url: $("ClientForm").data('url'),
                   data : serializedData,
                   type: 'post',
                   success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response.client.name)
                        console.log($("#ClientList"))
                        var block ='<div class="heading-section animate-box"> <h2>Client </h2> </div> </div> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="fh5co-blog animate-box"> <div class="inner-post"> <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/user.jpg" alt=""><i class="fa fa-user fa-5x" style="margin: 20px;"></i></a> </div> <div class="desc" style="padding-bottom: 2rem;"> <span class="posted_by"></span> <span class="comment"></a></span> <h3>'+ response.client.name +'</h3> <h3>'+ response.client.email +'</h3>  <a href="addexercise.html" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 1rem; margin-right: 2rem;">Add / Edit Exercises</a></div> <a href="client.html" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">View</a> </div> '
                        var test = '<h2>'+ response.client.name +'</h2>'
                        var card = '<div class="card mt-2" id="taskCard">'+ response.client.name +'<div class="card-body" ></div></div>';
                        $(block).appendTo("#clientList")
                        $("#clientList").append(test).html();
                    
                   }
               })
        $("#ClientForm")[0].reset()
    });

 
});
```

```html
<div class="fh5co-herome">
        <div class="fh5co-overlay-5"></div>
        <div class="fh5co-cover" data-stellar-background-ratio="0" style="background-image: url({% static 'coach/images/meghan-holmes.jpg' %});">
            <div class="desc animate-box">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 animate-box">
                            <h3 class="section-title">Add Client</h3>
                            <form class="contact-form" id="ClientForm" data-url="{% url 'addclient' %}">

                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
                                    {{ form.name }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                    {{ form.email }}
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button"  id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Add Client </client>
                                    
                                    
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% block content %}


    <div id="fh5co-blog-section">
        <div class="container" id="clientList">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">

        {% for client in clients %}


        
               
                        <div class="heading-section animate-box">
                            <h2>Client</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="fh5co-blog animate-box">
                            <div class="inner-post">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/user.jpg" alt=""><i class="fa fa-user fa-5x" style="margin: 20px;"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc" style="padding-bottom: 4rem;">
                                <span class="posted_by"></span>
                                <span class="comment"></a></span>
                                <h3>{{ client.name }}</h3>
                                <a href="addexercise.html" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 1rem; margin-right: 2rem;">Add / Edit Exercises</a>
                                <a href="client.html" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">View</a>
                            </div> 
                        

                
        
        
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="ward"></div>
        
        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>

    {% endblock %}

    <div id="fh5co-blog-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="heading-section animate-box">
                            <h2>Clients</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="fh5co-blog animate-box">
                            <div class="inner-post">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/user.jpg" alt=""><i class="fa fa-user fa-5x" style="margin: 20px;"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc" style="padding-bottom: 4rem;">
                                <span class="posted_by"></span>
                                <span class="comment"></a></span>
                                <h3>{ Client Name }</h3>
                                <a href="addexercise.html" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 1rem; margin-right: 2rem;">Add / Edit Exercises</a>
                                <a href="client.html" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">View</a>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
      

            </div>
                

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

view.py

```
def addclient(request):
form = ClientForm
clients = client.objects.filter(affiliation=request.user.id)


context = {'form': form ,'clients': clients}

form = ClientForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ClientForm(request.POST)
    print(form)

    if form.is_valid():
        print('adding client', form)
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        new_client = client.objects.create(name= name, email=email , affiliation=request.user)
        new_client.save()
        return JsonResponse({'client': model_to_dict(new_client)}, status=200)
    else:
        print('not adding client to the form 1333')
        return redirect('addclient')



return render(request, 'coach/addclient.html', context= context)
```

so i have tried to add a simple tittle with the response and Append() function value and it worked fine
but when i add the whole block it created it in html but it dont show it their is a picture of the problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var csrfToken = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

    $("#btn-submit").click(function() {
        var serializedData = $("#ClientForm").serialize();
        console.log("hey hey clients!");
        $.ajax({ 
                   url: $("ClientForm").data('url'),
                   data : serializedData,
                   type: 'post',
                   success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response.client.name)
                        console.log($("#ClientList"))
                        var block ='<div class="heading-section animate-box"> <h2>Client </h2> </div> </div> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="fh5co-blog animate-box"> <div class="inner-post"> <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/user.jpg" alt=""><i class="fa fa-user fa-5x" style="margin: 20px;"></i></a> </div> <div class="desc" style="padding-bottom: 2rem;"> <span class="posted_by"></span> <span class="comment"></a></span> <h3>'+ response.client.name +'</h3> <h3>'+ response.client.email +'</h3>  <a href="addexercise.html" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 1rem; margin-right: 2rem;">Add / Edit Exercises</a></div> <a href="client.html" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">View</a> </div> '
                        var test = '<h2>'+ response.client.name +'</h2>'
                        var card = '<div class="card mt-2" id="taskCard">'+ response.client.name +'<div class="card-body" ></div></div>';
                        $(block).appendTo("#clientList")
                        document.getElementById("clientList").appendChild(test)
                    
                   }
               })
        $("#ClientForm")[0].reset()
    });

 
});
```

Comment: i used your line code but i had to do some little changes , i created an element with DOM and put some content with the .innerHtml then i added it and it worked with simple boostrap list i guess the problem is from the block im trying to add it ,  Thank you for ur help :3